# Clickable text, new Intent, sqlite

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-intent

I have a database and a method, which can get all my info from my database to a TextView. It shows only the Title of each row, there are more columns, which I want to show on new Intent when I click on a Title. My question is, how can I make each title clickable and if clicked it opens up a new intent with the relevant information(need to pass the id)? Many thanks. :)

My History Activity -

```
public class HistoryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_layout);
        final LinearLayout linearLayoutBackground = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLinearLayout);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHistory);
        DataBaseHelper DataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);

        int backgroundImages[] = {R.drawable.background1,
                R.drawable.background2};
        final Drawable backgroundImage = getResources().getDrawable(
                backgroundImages[intValue]);
        linearLayoutBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundImage);

        DataBaseHelper.open();
        String HistoryData = DataBaseHelper.getListData();
        DataBaseHelper.closee();
        tv.setText(HistoryData);


    }

}
```

getListData method -

```
public String getListData() {
    open();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME1, columns, WHATTODONOW_COLUMN_ID, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int iTitle = c.getColumnIndex(WHATTODONOW_COLUMN_TITLE);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iTitle) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

HistoryLayout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/MainLinearLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="All the things you have already done!"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHistory"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="get info from db"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="25dp">
        </TextView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use clickable spannable string

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't this a typical use case for a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go from my experience.  First instead of using a ListView you look at ExpandableListView, which might accomplish what you want in one activity instead of having to start another intent.

Second, if you want to stick with the 2 intent design you have to pass some data from the current intent to the new one, you could do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this, yournewactivity.class);
                    // following line is an example of passing data to the new intent.
        i.putExtra(getString(R.string.str_selecteddialog), "1");
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
```

In the new intent that you have started in the onCreate you need to retrieve the data from the bundle:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // Log.i(TAG, " 022:... we got some extras");
        str_selecteddialog = getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.str_selecteddialog));
```

There are different types of put and get 'Extras' dependent on  variable types.  Now you have to decide:  Do I get all the data from the cursor and pass it to this new intent or Do I just pass the row id column, typically '_id' and query it in this activity.

Hope this helps.